# Full screen menu overlay when user presses the hamburger icon

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'd like to create a full menu screen overlay (with a list of options) that slides out from the top of the screen once the user presses the hamburger icon and overlays the browser (preferably without JS, and using HTML5/CSS3 - but if JS is necessary I don't mind using it).

What would be the best way of going about this?

I have uploaded a **[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/7e6w0Lcv/3/)** here.

HTML

```
<div id="tb"></div>
<div id="mt">&equiv;</div>
<div id="s1" class="s"></div>
```

CSS

```
#tb {
    height: 0.1em;
    background-color: #1f1f1f;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 2;
    width: 100%;
    box-shadow: 0 0 3px #1f1f1f;
}
#mt {
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 2;
    left: 90%;
    box-shadow: #1f1f1f 0px 0px 3px 0px;
    background-color: #1f1f1f;
    padding: 0.3em;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
    color: #ffffff
}
#menuIcon:hover {
    opacity: 0.6;
    cursor: pointer;
}
#s1 {
    background: url('http://static.tumblr.com/78708c8c0ab6a659f4323a82d54d4dc5/cjtdloz/V9Fmyvp0z/tumblr_static_red_redder_reddest.jpg') no-repeat center center;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
    height: 50em;
}
```

Comment: Check out this code: http://codepen.io/surjithctly/pen/pLDwe/

Comment: @RyanWillis - that rocks! Thanks for linking to it.

Comment: @Christina If you're looking for nav you can drag down, then check this one out (codepen.io/evolutionxbox/pen/dwxHe).

Or there's these (http://tympanus.net/Development/FullscreenOverlayStyles/) by Tympanus.net, which are very professional.